# Как вытащить картинку из тега?

Tags: xml, парсер, sax, java

Не могу понять, как реализовать работу sax parser так, чтобы в ленту еще и картинки грузились.

Класс парсера:

```
package app.kray.anddev;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.sax.Element;
import android.sax.EndElementListener;
import android.sax.EndTextElementListener;
import android.sax.RootElement;
import android.util.Xml;

public class NewParser {

    protected InputStream getInputStream() {
        URL feedUrl = null;
        try {
            feedUrl = new URL("http://anddev.ru/feed");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            feedUrl = null;
        }
        try {
            return feedUrl.openConnection().getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<PostItem> parse() {
        final PostItem currentPost = new PostItem();
        final ArrayList<PostItem> messages = new ArrayList<PostItem>();
        RootElement root = new RootElement("rss");
        Element channel = root.getChild("channel");
        Element item = channel.getChild("item");
        item.setEndElementListener(new EndElementListener() {
            public void end() {
                messages.add(currentPost.copy());
            }
        });
        item.getChild("title").setEndTextElementListener(
                new EndTextElementListener() {
                    public void end(String body) {
                        currentPost.title = body;
                    }
                });
        item.getChild("link").setEndTextElementListener(
                new EndTextElementListener() {
                    public void end(String body) {
                        currentPost.link = body;
                    }
                });
        item.getChild("description").setEndTextElementListener(
                new EndTextElementListener() {
                    public void end(String body) {
                        currentPost.description = body;
                    }
                });
        item.getChild("pubDate").setEndTextElementListener(
                new EndTextElementListener() {
                    public void end(String body) {
                        currentPost.setDate(body);
                    }
                });
        try {
            Xml.parse(this.getInputStream(), Xml.Encoding.UTF_8,
                    root.getContentHandler());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
        return messages;
    }
}
```

Подсказали пользоваться еще и `jasoup`, чтобы вытащить ссылки на картинки и грузить в `imageView`, опыта у меня в java мало, а разобраться очень хочется. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

первая часть - sax parser обмолачивает весь XML, разбивая на записи (`<item></item>`)

вторая часть - с помощью [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) вы распарсиваете значения, голый HTML, который вам насобирает SAX Parser. JSoup [умеет использовать строчки](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/parse-document-from-string) и возвращать структуры.

на официальном сайте очень много примеров

если хочется полного комфорта, то можно еще и [JAXB](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/xml/javax_xml_bind_jaxb.htm) заюзать превращая каждую запись в ленте в java-объект (POJO):

например:

```
class SiteItem:
    private String title;
    private String link;
    private String comments;
    ...
```